# Tradingview - how to define strategy entry price

Tags: tradingview-api, trading

Ok, this is driving me nuts...thinking it is not possible in Tradingview.

The basic code...

if longCondition
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=h[1], qty=100000/close)
lastTriangleColor := color.green

I need the strategy to use the crossover value of high[1] so that I can use that value for future exit calculations, but it will only use the close of the bar.

stop = makes it take the trade, but price is at close of bar, not cross
limit = makes it ignore the trade as the price is moving away from the cross

I have tried everything I can think of with no success.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!